# Why aren't the graphs displaying on this repository preview?

Tags: github

git: https://github.com/elijahpereira/Treehouse-Web-App-Dashboard
preview: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/elijahpereira/Treehouse-Web-App-Dashboard/blob/main/index.html

tried live preview and it's not showing. maybe there's another live preview link that will work and show the information correctly?